# What is the advantage of AES-GCM against CPA attack

Tags: aes

This questions is re GCM block-mode of AES. Assuming the TAG is cut to t bits, how can the strength of the cipher be calculated, that is, what is the Advantage of the cipher against CPA attack, and after how much authenticated data a new key has to be exchanged?

Answer (score 3):

I'll use the 2012 paper: [*"Breaking and Repairing GCM Security Proofs" by Iwata, Ohashi and Minematsu*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/438) as my primary source.

In said paper, the advantages for the privacy and authenticity game are stated. Only the latter one is being influenced by the tag length $\tau$.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\operatorname{Perm}(n)$ and $\tau$ be the parameters of GCM. Then for any $\mathcal A$ that makes at most $q$
>   encryption queries, where the total plaintext length is at most
>    $\sigma$ blocks and the maximum nonce length is at most $l_N$ blocks,
>    $$\textbf{Adv}^{\text{priv}}_{\operatorname{GCM}[\operatorname{Perm(n)},\tau]}(\mathcal
>  A)\leq
>  \frac{0.5(\sigma+q+1)^2}{2^n}+\frac{2^{22}q(\sigma+q)(l_N+1)}{2^n}$$

with $n=128$ because you pick AES here.

> **Theorem 2.** Let $\operatorname{Perm}(n)$ and $\tau$ be the parameters of GCM. Then for any $\mathcal A$ that makes at most $q$
>   encryption queries and $q'$ decryption queries, where the total plaintext length is at most
>    $\sigma$ blocks,the maximum nonce length is at most $l_N$ blocks and the maximum input length is at most $l_A$ blocks,
>    $$\textbf{Adv}^{\text{auth}}_{\operatorname{GCM}[\operatorname{Perm(n)},\tau]}(\mathcal
>  A)\leq
>  \frac{0.5(\sigma+q+q'+1)^2}{2^n}+\frac{2^{22}(q+q'+1)(\sigma+q)(l_N+1)}{2^n}+\frac{q'(l_A+1)}{2^\tau}$$

In theory you could just plug-in values into the theorem until you hit a security bounds that makes you feel uncomfortable and use it.

---

Or you could just follow [NIST SP 800-38D Appendix C (PDF)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf)'s guidance on short tags with AES-GCM. It contains nice tables and explanations thereof for 32-bit and 64-bit tags. If you do not intend to shorten the tag, then section 8 has guidance on message lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Section 8 of NIST SP 800-38D (Recommendation for Block Cipher Modes of peration: Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) and GMAC) deals with "**UNIQUENESS REQUIREMENT ON IVS AND KEYS**"

the initial few lines state that

> The probability that the authenticated encryption function ever will
>   be invoked with the same IV and the same key on two (or more) distinct
>   sets of input data shall be no greater than **2**<sup>**-32**</sup>.

See Details [here](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf)